# Mouse coordinates not accurate in Java?

Tags: java, controls, mouse

I just started working with mouse listeners in java and I ran into a problem with where I click and where objects show up. What I've been trying to do is make an object appear where I click, but where it shows up instead is below the mouse and a little to the right.

Any reason this is happening? All I am currently using is mouseX and mouseY as ints and setting it equal to evt.getX()/evt.getY() everytime the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

mouse coordinates are fine, but you're likely not using them correctly.

- Is your MouseListener added to the JFrame? If so, don't do that. Add it to the contentPane or the component that holds the objects being added.
- Also note that when you add components to a container, the add point is the upper left of the component, not the center. To make it the center, you'll have to do some easy math calculation.
- For more and better help, post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

i want to expand the wise words of "Hovercraft Full Of Eels"(??)

the coordinates you are getting are relative to the `JFrame` you are using, and you are adding the new object to the `contentPane`.

what's the different?

well, good you ask, the different is that the jFrame has a small border/bar in the sides,
[image]

means it's a bit bigeer then the `contentPane` and thus when you add the object it is a bit more to the right and down then what you expected

[image]